# io operation using same stream object

Tags: c++, filestream, iostream

I want to perform I/O operation in c++. I want to store a pointer to fstream object and using that same fstream I want to read and write to that file. Is it possible without using two different objects i.e ifstream for reading and ofstream for writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `fstream` can be used for reading and writing. Is this what you want to accomplish?

```
// Your fstream object
 std::fstream a("coco.txt");
 // Buffer
 char foo[100];

 // Write
 a<<"Hello"<<endl;
 // Rewind
 a.seekg(0,ios::beg);
 // Read
 a>>foo;

 // Display
 std::cout<<foo;
 // Clean up
 a.close();
```

Comment: This is what I was doing expecting to write and read but one stipulation to this is file must exist. Like object instantiation of fstream does not creates a file. And that was the reason I was not able to achieve what I asked in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an `fstream` is specifically intended to support both reading and writing (it derives from both `ifstream` and `ofstream`).

Comment: Almost. It derives from `istream` and `ostream` (via `iostream`).